# how to connect multiple views to a single tab bar item in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, tabview

I have a tab bar controller which has two items connected to two view controllers(say A & B) now I want to add a 3rd view controller (say C). But I don't want to add a third icon in tab view. When the user select the second icon it should render B or C depending on whether user has signed in or not.

[image: Storyboard Setup]

Comment: if anyone is down voting at least tell me why are you down voting?

Comment: Can you add what you have done till now here?

Comment: @IqbalInzamam: Questions usually get voted down on Stackoverflow when people seem to haven't tried to come up with a solution for themselves before asking for help. You should try to describe your thoughts for a possible approach in your question and specifically ask why this approach doesn't work or if there are better alternatives.

Comment: And dude: If you want to get helpful answers here, at least take the time to setup your questions properly. I just fixed your image that was only linked with a title "enter image description here". Otherwise you'll get a lot more down votes and even worse: No qualified answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just create another view controller for the tab bar item for which you want to display different views depending on the context. Let's call it `RouterViewController`. Then pass the information you need to decide which view controller to show to that `RouterViewController` and implement the necessary logic there.

From the `RouterViewController` you can now present whatever view controller you want (without animation). There are plenty of ways to do this, for example:

- Make your `RouterViewController` a subclass of **`UINavigationController`** and dynamically set its `rootViewController` property.
- Make your `RouterViewController` a **container view controller** and embed the desired view controller accordingly.
- Present a view controller modally (without animation) from your `RouterViewController`. *(I personally would discourage this option because presenting modal view controllers is intended for another purpose.)*

etc.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying the 1st way you suggested. So I added a navigation controller as the second item of the tab controller. Then I couldn't understand where to set the rootViewController of navigation controller. Is it in the viewDidLoad of the tabBarController and how to set it? Please help me.

Comment: I suspect you're using a storyboard? If yes: 1. Add your navigation controller as the second tab of the tab bar controller. 2. Create a subclass of `UINavigationController` and call it `RouterViewController`. 3. Select the navigation controller in your storyboard and set its class to `RouterViewController`. 4. In the `RouterViewController`'s `viewDidLoad()` method set the root view controller like this: `viewControllers = [theViewControllerYouWantToShow]`.

Comment: this may be a very stupid question. Sorry i'm very new to ios. I did as u said, the how do I connect UINavigationController and the UIController (B & C), through which type of segue. 
I did the fallowing 
if (...){
 viewControllers = [FirstViewController()]
}else{
viewControllers = [SecondViewController()]
}

but when I click second tab icon it loads a navigation ui with black screen
I have attached the story board diagram in the question

Comment: You don't do it with segues, you do it in code. However, if you simply instantiate an instance of your respective view controllers (`FirstViewController()`) you'll get a view controller with an empty (black) view because it's not linked to the storyboard in any way. In order to link it you need to get a reference to your storyboard in code and then call [instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistoryboard/1616214-instantiateviewcontroller) on it. Just google "instantiate view controller from storyboard" and you'll find a solution.